# How do I temporarily shut down my MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I have installed MediaWiki on my website. I want to shut it down temporarily, until I completely fill it with articles.

Is this possible? Is there any maintenance shut down feature?

(Version: 1.18.1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add to **LocalSettings.php**:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;
```

But of course admin is able to edit pages.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [`$wgReadOnly`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgReadOnly) is what you're looking for.